# Bootstrap issue, dropdown menu is hidden behind another element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm newbie in developing using bootstrap framework and I've faced problem that I'm unable to workaround.

I need to create page which consists from two parts: navigation part, content part. Content part should be scrollable and it consists from some generated data (javascript), so here is code:

```js
function loaddata() {
"use strict";
var i, divMain, divContent;
divMain = document.getElementById("data");
 for (i = 0; i < 100; i += 1)
  {
   divContent = document.createElement("div");
    divContent.setAttribute("id", "div_content" + i);
    divContent.innerHTML += "Some data " + i;
    divMain.appendChild(divContent);
  }
}
```

```css
html, body
{
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
#data
{
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 95%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<body  onload="loaddata()">
  <div class="nav">
    <div class='btn-group' role='group' aria-label='...'>
      <button class='btn btn-default'>Button 1</button>
      <button class='btn btn-default'>Button 2</button>
        <div class='btn-group'>
          <button type='button' class='btn btn-default dropdown-toggle' data-toggle='dropdown' aria-haspopup='true' aria-expanded='false'>Button 3</button>
          <ul class='dropdown-menu'>
          <li><input type='checkbox' checked>Value 1</li>
          <li><input type='checkbox' checked>Value 2</li>
          <li><input type='checkbox' checked>Value 3</li>
          </ul>
       </div>
    </div>
    <div>Some text..............................................</div>
    <div>Some text..............................................</div>
  </div>
  <div id="data">
  </div>
</body>
```

I'm able to fix the problem with hidden drop-down by changing position property of data div to non fixed or absolute, but in this case data isn't scrollable.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9y87xvdj/5/)

Please point me to right solution.

Comment: Does your navigation need to be always visible? The reason your dropdown is blocked is because the div under it has position: absolute. What this css rule does is remove it from the normal flow of the html and place it ontop of the other elements. In other words ontop of your dropdown.

Comment: Also, I can't get the inner scrollbar to ever be scrollable in chrome with your code above.  The outer scrollbar on the top window works though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit based on comment:

Set `.nav` `fixed`:

```js
function loaddata() {
  "use strict";
  var i, divMain, divContent;
  divMain = document.getElementById("data");
  for (i = 0; i < 100; i += 1) {
    divContent = document.createElement("div");
    divContent.setAttribute("id", "div_content" + i);
    divContent.innerHTML += "Some data " + i;
    divMain.appendChild(divContent);
  }
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  overflow-y: auto;
}
#data {
  margin-top: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 95%;
  /*overflow-y: scroll;*/
}
.nav {
  position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<body onload="loaddata()">
  <div class="nav">
    <div class='btn-group' role='group' aria-label='...'>
      <button class='btn btn-default'>Button 1</button>
      <button class='btn btn-default'>Button 2</button>
      <div class='btn-group'>
        <button type='button' class='btn btn-default dropdown-toggle' data-toggle='dropdown' aria-haspopup='true' aria-expanded='false'>Button 3</button>
        <ul class='dropdown-menu'>
          <li>
            <input type='checkbox' checked>Value 1</li>
          <li>
            <input type='checkbox' checked>Value 2</li>
          <li>
            <input type='checkbox' checked>Value 3</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="data">
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Navigation part (buttons) shouldn't be scrollable, so this isn't right solution. Anyway, thanks for comment.

Comment: I doubt it is @Syden. You have two scrollbars and you are hiding text in the data div with your navbar.